# vlookup referencing countif formula

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup, countif

I am trying to create either a vlookup or index/match formula to populate cells based on a list data validated cell.

The formula I currently have is as follows;

=INDEX($D$4:$D$9,MATCH(A30&B30,$A$4:$A$9&$B$4:$B$9,0))

Where A30 and B30 are the 2 lookup arrays, a4:a9 and b4:b9 are columns with data referring to (a) performance indicator titles and (b)actual and target titles (each performance indicator has an actual and target row) and d4:d9 is the value column referring to the 'actual' number for each PI and the target for each PI which are COUNTIF formulas from another sheet. Columns D-J have month titles with D being April and moving through the fiscal year each column to the right.

Example from cell A1

Performance Indicator       Actual/target       April     May     June

1                           Actual                3        6       4
1                           Target                4        4       4
2                           Actual                2        1       3
2                           Target                1        1       1

Using the formula I have already brings back a error #NA and I think it is to do with the fact that my formulas are referring to values which are gained through formulas. What Is the best way to get around this issue?

Comment: I take it you've committed that formula as an array formula, which is required?

Comment: Yes, the formula is array. The values in A4:A9 and B4:B9 are manually typed. Cell A30 is a validated list.

Comment: Whether the entries being referenced are the result of formulas or not is immaterial. Suggest you check that there is at least one actual value which meets your criteria. One way to do this would be the formula: =COUNTIFS(A4:A9,A30,B4:B9,B30) which should be non-zero.

Comment: Working now. XOR LX your comment was correct, the count if formula brought back a zero answer meaning that the cells being counted against were not matching in format/text. Many thanks,